# Excel nested if statements - need help troubleshooting

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need some fresh eyes.  I have been working on this incrementally and go from having it work to broken.  At this point my eyes are crossing and I could use some help.  Column H in this spreadsheet contains a machine id and column I is a date.  I want it to display nothing if both H and I are blank (This is the point where I broke it most recently and decided to ask for help.  This logic is not include.)  If either H or I but not both have a value, it will display "NO".  If both H and I have values, it will call a custom function that will create the directory if it does not already exist.  Additionally, I want to display "YES" if the directory is created or exists.  All of the functionality was working before I tried to display nothing if both H and I were empty.

This is the formula I am working with:

```
=IF(COUNTA(H21:I21)<>COLUMNS(H21:I21), "NO",IF(CREATEDIR(CONCATENATE(TEXT(I21,"yyyy"),"\",TEXT(I21,"m-d-yy"),"\",H21))=0,"YES", "NO"))
```

And this is the VBA function I am using(path details omitted)

`Function CREATEDIR(dateId)
    If Len(Dir("Z:\pathname\" & dateId, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "Z:\pathname\" & dateId
    End If
End Function`:

Comment: That helps with par.  The cell is empty if H and I are empty.  But the IF statement is still broken.  That was the other reason I came here for fresh eyes to see what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Update your UDF to the following so that it can build the full folder path provided in case it doesn't exist (this will handle both network folder paths such as `\\server\folder\subfolders\` as well as local or mapped folder paths such as `Z:\pathname\`).  You'll need to set the `sBeginPath` to whatever it should actually be:

```
Function CREATEDIR(dateID) As String

    Dim sBeginPath As String
    Dim sBuildPath As String
    Dim vFolder As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    sBeginPath = "C:\Test\"
    If Right(sBeginPath, 1) <> "\" Then sBeginPath = sBeginPath & "\"

    For Each vFolder In Split(sBeginPath & dateID, "\")
        If Len(vFolder) > 0 Then
            If Len(sBuildPath) = 0 Then
                If i > 0 Then
                    sBuildPath = "\\" & vFolder & "\"
                Else
                    sBuildPath = vFolder
                End If
            Else
                If i > 0 Then
                    sBuildPath = sBuildPath & vFolder & "\"
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    sBuildPath = sBuildPath & "\" & vFolder
                End If
            End If
            If (Len(sBuildPath) > 0) And (i = 0 Or i >= 3) Then
                If Len(Dir(sBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sBuildPath
            End If
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next vFolder

    CREATEDIR = "YES"

End Function
```

Then update your formula to the following (using the `CHOOSE` method as suggested by @pnuts):

```
=CHOOSE(COUNTA(H21:I21)+1,"", "NO",CREATEDIR(CONCATENATE(TEXT(I21,"yyyy"),"\",TEXT(I21,"m-d-yy"),"\",H21)))
```